# Lsp-metals submode fails to detect metals already installed in the system

Tags: emacs, scala-metals

I have Ubuntu system that i was trying to install scala development environment to.

I ahve installed `coursier` and from it installed everyting else - `scala`, `sbt`, `metals`. I have added that to the `PATH`, and now all those things open from command line without an issue.

However, when i try to launch `lsp`, after i am propmted for the supporting server, i get an attempt to install `metals` starting with `coursier`, and that attempt fails with some emacs error. Is there a way to ensure that installed scala tools are visible and available to lsp-metals?